# Rails 4: Pass attribute's value into the model for dynamic vailidation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, controller, attributes

In my 'Entry' model...

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
```

...I am trying to pass an attribute's value directly into the data validation below (the attribute that will dynamically update is ':wpu', and the value is an integer based on the user's form submission. There are three user options from a drop-down menu the will submit a value for ':wpu'; for the sake of this conversation, consider the value either  '5', '10', or '20').

```
validates :text, length: { is: DYNAMIC_VALUE_WOULD_GO_HERE,
    tokenizer: lambda { |str| str.squish.gsub('&'){''}.scan(/\w+/) }
    }
```

This validates when the string attribute's word count ':text' is equal to the integer of the other attribute mentioned earlier, ':wpu'. The code above works perfect if I replace the 'DYNAMIC_VALUE_WOULD_GO_HERE' with a '5', '10', or '20', but I haven't been successful in placing a dynamic value in there based on a user's input.

I've worked on this thing--probably has a simple answer--for 3 days now, but with no success.

Things I have tried:

1) Using attr_reader and calling the attributes value
2) Passing controller method parameters to the model

I am open to any suggestions and other methods. I am a beginner in ruby and rails.

Here is my full model code as it stands. It doesn't currently work as I haven't been able to pass through 'params'. Otherwise, without trying to make this dynamic, everything works fine if I remove the random experimental method below.

```
    class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :story
    attr_reader :wpu

    #method used to generate 'wpu' | which is words per user in Story
    def self.storywpu

        #story ID from EntriesController
        current_entry_story_id = Entry.find(params[:id]).story_id

        #returns 'wpu' | which is words per user in Story
        storywpu = Story.find(current_entry_story_id).wpu

        return storywpu
    end

    #strips ALL white space before form submission
    auto_strip_attributes :text, :nullify => false, :squish => true

    #validates each field has been filled out
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :story_id, presence: true
    validates :text, presence: true, autocomplete: false

    #validates word count is exactly 'wpu' | which is words per user in Story
    validates :text, length: { is: self.storywpu,
        tokenizer: lambda { |str| str.squish.gsub('&'){''}.scan(/\w+/) }
        }
end
```

And here is a related portion of my controller for reference...

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_entry, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def create 

    #New text entry
    @entry = Entry.create(entry_params)
    #Related story params
    @story = Story.find(@entry.story_id)
    @storyWPU = Story.find(@entry.story_id).wpu
    @word_count = @entry.text.squish.gsub('&'){''}.scan(/\w+/).size.to_i
    @wordsLeft = @storyWPU - @word_count


    if @word_count.nil?
        @response = 'enter ' + @wordsLeft.to_s + ' words'
    elsif @wordsLeft == 1
        @response = 'enter ' + @wordsLeft.to_s + ' word'
    elsif @wordsLeft < 0
        @response = @wordsLeft.abs.to_s + ' too many!'
    else
        @response = 'enter ' + @wordsLeft.to_s + ' words'
    end

    respond_to do |format|

        if @entry.save
            format.html { redirect_to edit_story_path(@story), notice: 'Nice!' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @entry }
        else
            format.html { redirect_to edit_story_path(@story), notice: @response }
            format.json { render json: @entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end

    private    
    def set_entry
      @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
    end

    private
    def entry_params
      params.require(:entry).permit(:text, :user_id, :story_id, :wpu)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I went about this all wrong. I've solved this by virtually moving the dynamic validation into the controller. Basically I was trying to avoid saving to the database if the amount of words submitted in a text field didn't match one of the attribute's values.

Everything is working now. Here is my controller 'create' code for reference...

```
def create 

    #New entry
    @entry = Entry.new(entry_params)

    #story variables
    @story = Story.find(@entry.story_id)
    @storyWPU = Story.find(@entry.story_id).wpu
    @word_count = @entry.text.squish.gsub('&'){''}.scan(/\w+/).size.to_i
    @wordsLeft = @storyWPU - @word_count

    if @word_count.nil?
        @response = 'enter ' + @wordsLeft.to_s + ' words'
    elsif @wordsLeft == 1
        @response = 'enter ' + @wordsLeft.to_s + ' word'
    elsif @wordsLeft < 0
        @response = @wordsLeft.abs.to_s + ' too many!'
    else
        @response = 'enter ' + @wordsLeft.to_s + ' words'
    end

    respond_to do |format|

        if @wordsLeft == 0 && @entry.save
            format.html { redirect_to edit_story_path(@story), notice: 'Nice!' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @entry }
        else
            format.html { redirect_to edit_story_path(@story), notice: @response }
            format.json { render json: @entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```